# How to get the word boundary in ZZ_CMAP_PACKED?

Tags: java, unicode, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin, word-boundary

I am trying to write my first Elasticsearch Analysis Plugin, and I found a Extensiable Standard Analyser Plugin project from github:[elasticsearch-analysis-standardext](https://github.com/bbguitar77/elasticsearch-analysis-standardext), in the project it provides codes below:

```java
   /** 
    * Word Boundary "character classes" that are used in the ZZ_CMAP_PACKED 
    * string 
    */ 
   public static final Character WB_CLASS_BREAK               = '\0'; 
   public static final Character WB_CLASS_LETTER              = '\176'; 
   public static final Character WB_CLASS_NUMERIC             = '\200'; 
   public static final Character WB_CLASS_MID_LETTER          = '\202'; 
   public static final Character WB_CLASS_MID_NUMBER          = '\203'; 
   public static final Character WB_CLASS_MID_NUMBER_LETTER   = '\204'; 
   public static final Character WB_CLASS_EXTENDED_NUM_LETTER = '\205'; 
   public static final Character WB_CLASS_SINGLE_QUOTE        = '\212'; 
   public static final Character WB_CLASS_DOUBLE_QUOTE        = '\213';
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/bbguitar77/elasticsearch-analysis-standardext/blob/cc63b2a850e688d1e52c6274517317d6283da46c/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/ExtensibleStandardTokenizerImpl.java#L69-L81)

I want to know how to get these word boundaries' character classes.

I ask the author with issue: [How to get word boundaries "character classes"? #2](https://github.com/bbguitar77/elasticsearch-analysis-standardext/issues/2), but it seems that the author won't answer my question.

I try to read the Unicode Text Segmentation documents: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/ , but I really can't found what I want since it is hard and long to read.

I download the Standard Analyser Code from lucene repository, it is here: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/releases/lucene-solr/8.1.0/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard

It seems that the `StandardTokenizerImpl.java` class is generated from `StandardTokenizerImpl.jflex`, can I get these word boundaries' character classes with the help of [jfex](https://jflex.de/)

Thanks for someone helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I found that we can get this world boundaries from the document: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries, and since the project [elasticsearch-analysis-standardext](https://github.com/bbguitar77/elasticsearch-analysis-standardext) is really old version of elasticsearch. It won't work with Elasticsearch version = 7.3.2.

And we can found that now Lucene don't support simple world boundaries like ALetter, it's format will be

```
MidLetterEx         = [\p{WB:MidLetter}\p{WB:MidNumLet}\p{WB:SingleQuote}]
```

we can see that from the file [`StandardTokenizerImpl.jflex`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/8.1.0/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizerImpl.jflex)

So if you want to get the world boundary from the  ZZ_CMAP_PACKED, you should refer to the document [Word_Boundaries](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries).

May this will help you if you want to write an custom StandardTokenizer.

Also you can refer to the ClassicTokenizer from Lucene project, it will help you!